# Apply specific layout from custom template with VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, automation, powerpoint

```
Sub ImportCharts()

Dim strTemp As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFileSpec As String
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oPic As Shape

strPath = ActivePresentation.Path & "\Images\"
strFileSpec = "*.png"
strTemp = Dir(strPath & strFileSpec)


Do While strTemp <> ""
    Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.count + 1, ppLayoutCustom)
    Set oPic = oSld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPath & strTemp, _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=0.45 * 72, _
    Top:=0.8 * 72, _
    Width:=10.1 * 72, _
    Height:=6.25 * 72) '
    strTemp = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

In the Do while loop the ppLayoutCustom adds the first custom layout. But I want to add Content Page layout as my custom layout (Refer image).

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuKM9.png)

Comment: Is the Theme you try  using a standard "Office Theme"? Or a custom one? My 365 Powerpoint does not show a theme name as the one you need. Is this theme **used on another existing slide of the presentation**? If already used, it should be simple to solve the problem, if not, you can determine the theme bay iteration between `Designs.CustomLayouts` ...

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru it is a custom theme. The below answer worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/apply-specific-layout-from-custom-template-with/8b78b1d7-2e07-4731-829c-499ee5405574) has the same issue and this answer is mostly restating what has already been shown there.

If you know that the index of your custom layout "Content Page" will always be 3, for example, then you can go about it like this:

```
With ActivePresentation
    .Slides.AddSlide _
        Index:=.Slides.Count + 1, _ 
        pCustomLayout:=.Designs(1).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(3)
End With
```

If you aren't certain that your custom layout will always have the same index, you'll need to first iterate through all of the custom layouts, find the index of the one you want, and then use the code above.  Of course, you would replace the `3` with the true index of your custom layout.